# Android button crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, share-intent

I have developed a actionbar share button, however when I run the app the button does work but it crashes the application when I try to share the images with other apps. For example if I share the image with Twitter or message the application just crashes and says that "Twitter or Message has crashed.

Comment: please put it crash exception as well. It will be better to understand peorblem

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRA_STREAM` [is supposed to hold a `content:` `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM).

In practice, you can often use a `file:` `Uri` pointing to a file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), though that will be a problem more and more as time goes along.

You are trying to use `android.resource:`. Few apps support `android.resource:` `Uri` values in general, let alone for `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Your choices are:

1. Write the resources out to files, then use `FileProvider` or perhaps `file:` `Uri` values
2. Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve your resources via `content:` `Uri` values
3. Do not attempt to share resources

Beyond that, also note that your `android.resource` `Uri` seems rather mangled, as you seem to have a newline character and the literal string `"getPackageName()"` as part of the value.

Comment: Could you please show me sample code that can help me or using my code